# Gitlab CI/CD Deployer SSH Connection timed out

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to automatically deploy a PHP application via [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) after pushing to my gitlab repository. Once a *php:7.3-alpine* Dockerfile with [Kaniko](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html) is builded, Deployer will be successfully installed, but the SSH connection to my local Ubuntu server fails

> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 2222: Connection timed out

This **only** happens when I am deploying from within the gitlab runner, a manual deployment runs as expected.

I am not certain if a SSH connection from within a gitlab runner is even possible or maybe there is also a more convenient solution. Because I am pretty new to the whole docker and CI/CD Pipeline experience, please bear with me.